# Cómo conservar el id con AUTO_INCREMENT en una base de datos de mysql de un dato que se envía desde el frontend

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

Estoy trabajando con una validación de formulario con React en frontend, mysql y express en el backend, todo funciona perfectamente, pero al momento hacer la validación de error diciéndole al usuario que por favor rellene el formulario correctamente y posteriormente, rellenándolo correctamente, envía los datos del usuario con Id único a mysql, pero mysql lo guarda con el ID 2 en lugar del ID 1, ¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar esto?
P.D. Uso AUTO_INCREMENT en mysql para el ID.

Código MySQL

```
 CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    fullname VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    correo VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE users 
    modify id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Codigo backend

```js
    const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require('../database');


router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const users = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users ');
    res.send(users);
    
});

router.post('/', async (req, res)=> {
    const {username, password, fullname, correo} = req.body;
    try{
         await pool.query('INSERT INTO users set ?',[{username, password, fullname, correo}]); 
         console.log('fresco')
         res.sendStatus(200)
    }catch(e){
        res.sendStatus(403)
    }
    
});
```

Codigo Frontend

```js
const SignUp = () => {
    
    const [fullname, setFullname]= useState({campo:'', valido:null});
    const [username, setUsername]= useState({campo:'', valido:null});
    const [email, setEmail]= useState({campo:'', valido:null});
    const [password, setPassword]= useState({campo:'', valido:null});
    const [password2, setPassword2]= useState({campo:'', valido:null});
    const [terminos, setTerminos] = useState(false);
    const [formValido, setFormValido] = useState(null)

    const expresiones = {
        usuario: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{4,16}$/, // Letras, numeros, guion y guion_bajo
        nombre: /^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,40}$/, // Letras y espacios, pueden llevar acentos.
        password: /^.{4,12}$/, // 4 a 12 digitos.
        correo: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/
        /* telefono: /^\d{7,14}$/ // 7 a 14 numeros. */
    }

    const onsubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();    

        if(
            fullname.valido === 'true' &&
            username.valido === 'true' &&
            password.valido === 'true' &&
            password2.valido === 'true' &&
            email.valido === 'true' &&
            terminos
            
        ){
            try{
                axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api',{
                    fullname: fullname.campo,
                    username: username.campo,
                    correo: email.campo,
                    password: password.campo 
                
                }).then(() =>{
                    setFullname({campo: '', valido: null});
                    setUsername({campo: '', valido: ''});
                    setPassword({campo: '', valido: null});
                    setPassword2({campo: '', valido: 'null'});
                    setEmail({campo: '', valido: null});
                    setFormValido(true);
                })
            }catch(e){
                console.log(e)
                if(403){
                   console.log('mamaste')
                }
            }
            
        }else{
            setFormValido(false)
        }       
    } 
    
    
    const validarPassword2 = () => {
        if(password.campo.length > 0){
            if(password.campo !== password2.campo){
                setPassword2((prevState) => {
                    return {...prevState, valido: 'false'}
                });
            } else {
                setPassword2((prevState) => {
                    return {...prevState, valido: 'true'}
                });
        
            }
        }   
    }
    const onChangeTerminos = (e) =>{
        setTerminos(e.target.checked)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No parce haber una causa aparente mas que ya hallas guardado un registro previo, intenta resetear el contador

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a modificar el script SQL de forma que al definir la clave primaria de users lo pongas así:

```
...
 id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
...
```

Eliminando la sentencia de `ALTER TABLE`. Una vez hecho eso, borra la BD por completo y créala de nuevo, con eso debería de funcionar.